# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xyz'

Tags: django, python-3.x

Running Python3.6.2. My code in process_sqs_messages.py up to line 3:

```
__author__ = 'Chris'
import boto3
from xyz.settings import SQS_QUEUE_NAME
```

Here is my stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bin/process_sqs_messages.py", line 3, in <module>
  from xyz.settings import SQS_QUEUE_NAME
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xyz'
```

Directory structure:

```
Project
|    
+-- bin
|  |
|  +-- process_sqs_messages.py
|    
+-- xyz
|  |  
|  +-- __init__.py
|  +-- settings.py
```

My installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'xyz',
]
```

Anyone know why i'm getting this error?

Comment: Have you tried doing `python manage.py shell` and `import xyz`? That might provide some clues.

Comment: running ```python manage.py shell``` produced this error


```django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.```


So I added ```export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="xyz.settings"``` to my virtualenv bin/activate file which fixed that error but original error still persists.

Comment: ran ```python manage.py shell ``` and then ```import xyz``` and it worked great but doesn't work outside the shell...still can't find my xyz module

Answer (score 0):

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code)

> Note that django.conf.settings isn’t a module – it’s an object. So
>   importing individual settings is not possible

```
from django.conf.settings import DEBUG  # This won't work.
```

You have to access the settings module like this

```
 from django.conf import settings

    if settings.DEBUG:
        # Do something
```

Comment: No, same error occurs. I'm sure the rule applies but my xyz is an app with a ```__init__.py```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work but I don't know why. Hopefully someone can shed some light on the fix. I was browsing the web trying to fix this error and here's what I did/found.

I first created a setup.py file at the project level, so

```
Project
|    
+-- setup.py
```

I then added this code to the setup.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='xyz',
  version='0.1.0',
  description='XYZ',
  author='Chris',
  author_email='none@none.com',
  url='http://www.none.com/',
  packages=['xyz', ],
  )
```

I then ran `python setup.py install` and (here's where I get lost) it installed the package. It created a build directory, egg info, site-packages under my virtualenv, etc.

Last I ran my command `python bin/process_sqs_messages.py` and it succeeded. No errors.

If you can help me and others, please comment/explain what I did because I can't :/

Comment: It sounds to me like something in your `PYTHON_PATH` wasn't clicking. After you run `python setup.py install` with that command, it added the `xyz` package to your `virtualenv`'s site packages directory. I'm guessing if you make a change to the `xyz` app in your Django project, the changes won't be reflected. First, I'd inspect the value of your `PYTHON_PATH` and then maybe try deleting and recreating your `virtualenv`?